# How to move airline status bar to the bottom of the editor?

Tags: statusline, plugin-airline

There is VIM's default bar below my Airline's status bar, which causes file information to be viewed twice (as shown in the image). How can I move my airline's bar to the bottom? I have tried adding `set noshowmode` but it didn't slove my problem.

[image]

Comment: That bottom line is the message window. You can't remove it. Besides the filename only shows temporarily there...until Vim has a message to display. Or you can hit `Ctrl-L` to clear it.

Answer (score 2):

In [Vim 9.0.0114](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f39cfb72629f3e7fefaf578a3faa2619cd0654f8)–9.0.0339 and [Neovim 0.8 (prerelease)](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases), `set cmdheight=0` hides the command line. Zero cmdheight was removed in [Vim 9.0.0340](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/a2a8973e51a0052bb52e43a2b22e7ecdecc32003).

Answer (score 1):

That's not really possible.

The last line is used not only to display messages and information, but also to enter Ex commands (the commands starting with a colon, such as `:w`, `:q`, `:e filename`, etc.), also where you can type a search pattern if you start a search using `/` or `?`.

Furthermore, that line is also used to display messages, such as error messages when you try to save a file but don't have permissions to write to it, or when you're searching for a term that's not present in the buffer.

The fact that the information in the message line is *occasionally* duplicating some information that's in the airline bar doesn't mean it should be gotten rid of.

The `'showmode'` option, when set, causes Vim to display `--INSERT--` in the message line when in insert mode. That's indeed a duplicated information from the one set up by the vim-airline plug-in, so the plug-in will by default disable that option to avoid that particular case of duplication.

Comment: would it be possible to reverse the order of vim-airline and the vim bar?